# Запятая перед "как" на конкретных примерах

Tags: пунктуация

Пытаюсь разобраться в правиле, но вводят в недоумение вот такие вот варианты:

**1)**

> Половина даже, бывало, подохнет, а воспитанию не поддаются: стоят на
>   дворе - все дивятся и даже от стен шарахаются, а все только на небо, 
>   как птицы,  глазами косят.

Тест на сайте "грамота.ру" исправил мой вариант без запятых, аргументировав это так: "Сравнительный оборот должен быть выделен запятыми".

Но почему? Разве это не образ действия? Мы же можем заменить это выражением "по-птичьи", а в таких случаях запятые ставиться не должны.

**2)**

> Кричит, как орел: стой, стрелять буду!

Тоже самое: "Сравнительный оборот должен быть выделен запятыми".

Почему? Ведь здесь можно заменить на "по-орлиному" или вообще написать "кричит орлом", к примеру. Как же тут может стоять запятая?

**3)** Вариант

> Внизу, как зеркало, блестела вода

вообще использован в качестве примера сравнительного оборота.

Но чем он отличается от выражения: "Тропинка извивалась как змея"? Почему  в случае тропинки аргументируется, дескать, она извивалась по-змеинному, а в случае озера игнорируется тот факт, что оно могло блестеть "зеркально", "по-зеркальному", "зеркалом"?

**4)**

> Юноша, как и мужчина, должен...

Правильно ли понимаю, что это сравнительный оборот и запятая нужна?

**5)**

> Попугай, как птица, умеет летать.

А этот оборот как рассматривать? Уточнение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего, не стоит преувеличивать уровень комментариев в этих самых диктантах. Когда видишь, как написано у классика, правило подобрать всегда можно. А вариант "можно ли по-другому" обычно не рассматривается.

> Но почему? Разве это не образ действия? Мы же можем заменить это
>   выражением "по-птичьи",

Можно и так трактовать. Тогда запятые, естественно, не потребовались бы.
Но реально тут трудно говорить об образе действия. Маловероятно, что автор подозревает реальных птиц в способности "косить" глазами.

> а в таких случаях запятые ставиться не должны.

Вы преувеличиваете значение этого правила. На самом деле это не правило даже, а некий признак, вспомогательный инструмент. Прямого указания типа "если можно заменить на наречие, то никогда не обособляется" нигде нет. 
Сама "Грамота" об этом пишет вполне честно.

> Если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия, например: Тропинка извивалась как
>   змея. В таких случаях оборот с КАК можно заменить наречием
>   (ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ) или существительным в творительном падеже (ЗМЕЕЙ). **К
>   сожалению, не всегда обстоятельства образа действия можно с полной
>   уверенностью отличить от обстоятельств сравнения.**

http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

> Почему? Ведь здесь можно заменить на "по-орлиному" или вообще написать
>   "кричит орлом", к примеру. Как же тут может стоять запятая?

Нет, вот тут-то никак нельзя. И дело не в том, что там Людмила написала насчет разных-де орлиных криков, а в том, что реальные орлы никогда не кричат "стой, кто идет". Здесь явно сравнение, уподобление даже, причем только по отдельным качествам.

Вы, меняя на наречия, привносите совершенно не предполагаемый смысл, подчас совершенно фантастический.

> Почему в случае тропинки аргументируется, дескать, она извивалась
>   по-змеинному, а в случае озера игнорируется тот факт, что оно могло
>   блестеть "зеркально", "по-зеркальному", "зеркалом"?

Аналогичный случай. Способность к блеску - не главное и не характерное качество зеркала. Предполагая тут образ действия, вы привносите излишний смысл. Теоретически такая трактовка возможна, но здесь она несколько противоестественна.

> Правильно ли понимаю, что это сравнительный оборот и запятая нужна?

"Как и" - это вообще особый случай, он почти исключает все трактовки, кроме уподобления, а уподобление всегда обособляется.

> А этот оборот как рассматривать? Уточнение?

Не знаю контекста, но скорее всего это значение причины. "Попугай. будучи птицей..." В таком случае это вообще не сравнительный оборот, а приложение. Такое "причинное" приложение всегда обособляется.

Answer (score 4):

1) Половина даже, бывало, подохнет, а воспитанию не поддаются: стоят на дворе - все дивятся и даже от стен шарахаются, а все только на небо, как птицы, глазами косят.

```
 Разве это не образ действия? Мы же можем заменить это выражением
 "по-птичьи", а в таких случаях запятые ставиться не должны.
```

Нет, дело не в том, КАК они косятся, а в том, что они это вообще делают, как и птицы, т. е. сравниваются с птицами по признаку отношения к небу.

2) Кричит, как орел: стой, стрелять буду!

```
можно заменить на "по-орлиному" или вообще написать "кричит орлом",
к примеру. Как же тут может стоять запятая?
```

*Смотрит орлом* сказать возможно, т. е. победно, уверенно, а вот *кричит орлом* — не понимаю, как это, здесь скорее кричит подобно орлу, т. е. совершает такое же действие, заменить наречием образа действия нельзя. Это сравнение по признаку совершения действия (орёл кричит в иных ситуациях, и он кричит).

3) Внизу, как зеркало, блестела вода.

Вода сравнивается с зеркалом по признаку блеска. Блестеть зеркалом нельзя, можно быть зеркалом, лечь зеркалом. Вот если бы было "Вода как зеркало" — *как зеркало* было бы сказуемым и не обособлялось бы.

"Тропинка извивалась как змея" — по-змеиному, змеёй — воспринимается наречием "зигзагообразно". Озеро же блестит так же, как блестит зеркало, а "зеркально" имеет другое значение — "обратно, как отражение"

4) Юноша, как и мужчина, должен...

Да, это сравнительный оборот с "как и...", запятая нужна.

5) Попугай, как птица, умеет летать.

Это не уточнение, а приложение с причинным значением: Попугай, он же птица, умеет летать. Попугай, так как он птица, умеет летать.

Comment: А почему отметается вариант "по-орлиному"?

Comment: Да потому что это бессмысленно: нет у орла какого-то особого крика, одни издают клёкот, другие пищат, третьи издают что-то типа мяуканья. Вот взгляд - да, он смотрит не моргая. И вообще это символ гордыни и величия, голос ему ни к чему, орлы редко кричат. У Бунина речь идёт о ситуации, когда князь возомнил себя божеством, которому всё позволено, положил глаз на невесту сына, а они сбежали. Вот он догнал и кричит, как орёл, т.е. как царь, хотя бы среди птиц.Рассказывает балладу крестьянская девочка, которая знает об образе жизни орлов.

Comment: *Да потому что это бессмысленно: нет у орла какого-то особого крика*- гм... А я точно должен знать орнитологию, чтобы разобраться в пунктуации?

Answer (score 2):

Внизу, **как зеркало**, блестела вода. Но: вода блестит **как зеркало**.

**С учетом одной семантики  вопросы с обособлением сравнительного оборот не решишь, важна структура предложения:**  распространенность, позиция оборота.

Вода **блестит как зеркало** - это устойчивое выражение (= ярко блестит). Но распространим предложение, изменим позицию, и тот же оборот уже обособляется.

**Примеры:**

"Удивительный портсигар, блестит **как зеркало**" (В. Пелевин).

"Его гладкая поверхность еще не повреждена выветриванием и **блестит как зеркало**" (И. А. Ефремов).

"Бывает на такую паутину ложится осенняя густая роса и при первом свете солнца луг **блестит как лед**" (М. Пришвин).

Классики, как правило, не ошибаются,  а вот в обычных текстах пользователи ставят или не ставят запятые по своему усмотрению.

**От себя лично могу добавить**, что все "**упражнения"   по определению семантики сравнительного оборота  - это, как правило, пустая и бессмысленная трата времени.** Сравнительный оборот - это  фигура речи, художественный прием, его смысл - сравнение двух предметов, признаков или  действий,  и обособленность или необособленность оборота к семантике прямого отношения не имеет. Можно долго рассуждать об особенностях "орлиного крика", но с пунктуацией это мало связано. Автор строит предложение таким образом, что оборот или является **обособленным попутным сравнением** в распространенном предложении, или **необособленным обстоятельством в нераспространенном предложении**, и это вычисляется по структуре.