# обстоятельство сравнения или действия

Tags: обороты-с-как

Чистые от трав протоки блестят как зеркала и вокруг бесконечная тишина.

Answer (score 1):

*Чистые от трав протоки блестят (как?), **как зеркала**, и вокруг бесконечная тишина.*

Как зеркала - обстоятельство  образа действия, выраженное сравнительным оборотом. Не знаю, как Вы подразделяете на обстоятельства сравнения или действия. Иногда такие обстоятельства называют просто "сравнение", а по значению обстоятельства бывают обстоятельствами образа, меры и степени действия, места, времени, причины, цели, условия, уступки. Обстоятельства сравнения не встречала.

Answer (score 1):

1) Вот диктант.

https://dictants.com/5-klass/itogovye-diktanty-za-5-klass/418-itogovyj-diktant-znojnyj-polden.html

Диктанты 5 класс / Итоговые диктанты за 5 класс
Пышет знойный полдень. Совершенная тишина. Не колыхнет зеленый широкий пруд. Он точно спит в своих отлогих берегах. Камыши стоят неподвижно. ***Материк и чистые от трав протоки блестят как зеркалА.***

2) Правильно задать вопрос так: **сравнительный оборот или обстоятельство образа действия?**

В данном случае сравнительный оборот не обособлен, то есть является не попутным сравнением, а обстоятельством образа действия, которое входит в основной состав предложения.

3) А если изменить предложение: ***Чистые от трав протоки блестят как зеркалА,  и вокруг бесконечная тишина.***

Пожалуй, мало что изменилось. На оборот падает логическое ударение, паузы нет. **Этот вариант более вероятен, хотя и обособление не запрещено.**

Интонационный вариант с обособлением в принципе возможен, поэтому  эта задача может иметь два решения: ***Чистые от трав протоки блестЯт, как зеркалА,  и вокруг бесконечная тишина.***

Подробно подобный вопрос обсуждался  на форуме: 
 [Запятая перед "как" на конкретных примерах](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426775/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85).