# Пела(,) как птица. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Пела как птица.

Конечно запятой нет и быть не может! *Как птица* можно заменить на *по-птичьи*, на первый план выходит обстоятельственный оттенок, поэтому запятой нет.

А школьный учебник издательства "Дрофа" говорит, что запятая нужна. Как это можно давать детям? Или я что-то не понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, наличие запятой зависит от предложения. Один вариант: "Как она пела? Она пела как птица", тут сравнение входит в сказуемое. Другой вариант: "И каждый день она пела, как птица, очаровывая публику", тут сравнение легко изымается из предложения.

Во-вторых, вопрос, очень похожий на Ваш, я уже задавал на этом форуме. Там даже фигурировало именно сравнение с птицей и замешательство на счёт возможности замены на "по-птичьи". Ознакомьтесь: [Запятая перед "как" на конкретных примерах](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426775/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: Во втором примере запятая также может не ставиться.

Comment: Если фраза изымается из предложения, то запятая не нужна. Вряд ли автор такой фразы действительно хочет сказать, что она пела именно как настоящая птица. Скорее всего, это сравнение, а пела она не как птица, а как человек. Так что во втором примере запятая не нужна кроме ситуаций, когда автор хочет буквально сказать то, что написано. Но это ведь фигуральное выражение.